# Split an .xml-file with XSLT

Tags: xslt, xpath

I have written an XSL-file, that reads some filenames from the source file and uses this filenames, to split another file (which is opened in the XSL-file via the *document()* function). The filenames are used to create several output files and certain parts of the *loaded* file are written to these output files.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="Root">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//Link"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Link">
        <xsl:result-document href="{@url}" method="xml">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="document('Input.xml')//Node"/>
        </xsl:result-document>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Node">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>

        <xsl:if test="following-sibling::*[1][self::NextPart]">
            <!-- write some test node -->
            <xsl:element name="FoundNextPart"/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The sourcefile looks something like this

```
<Root>
    <SomeNode>
        <Link url="part_0.xml"/>
        <Link url="part_1.xml"/>
        <Link url="part_2.xml"/>
    </SomeNode>
</Root>
```

The *Input.xml* file will have a structure like this

```
<Root>
    <Node>
        <PartContent>
            <ImportantContent>0</ImportantContent>
        </PartContent>
    </Node>
    <Node>
        <PartContent>
            <ImportantContent>0</ImportantContent>
        </PartContent>
    </Node>
    <NextPart/>
    <Node>
        <PartContent>
            <ImportantContent>1</ImportantContent>
        </PartContent>
    </Node>
    <Node>
        <PartContent>
            <ImportantContent>1</ImportantContent>
        </PartContent>
    </Node>
    <NextPart/>
</Root>
```

My problem is now with the

```
<xsl:template match="Node">
```

I want to copy the content of the *Input.xml* up to the first appearance of the

```
<NextPart/>
```

node. Then I want to somehow *break* out of the current nodeset (*//Node* of the *Input.xml*) and continue with the next *//Link*. But for this next *Link* (file) I want to copy the content of the *Input.xml* between the first and the second appearance of the

```
<NextPart/>
```

node.

I'm not sure if this is feasible in any way. Also I'm not sure if my approach can be used for this.
I've read something like using

```
<xsl:call-template name="copy">
```

to use the following-sibling of the current node as a parameter. But anyway I have to pass the current count of the

```
<NextPart/>
```

so that I know, which content to copy!?

Answer (score 2):

How about processing and grouping that `Input.xml` once with e.g.

```
<xsl:variable name="groups">
  <xsl:for-each-group select="document('Input.xml')/Root/*" group-ending-with="NextPart">
    <group>
      <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()[self::Node]"/>
    </group>
  </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:variable>
```

in a global variable, then in your template you do

```
<xsl:template match="Link">
    <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()"/>
    <xsl:result-document href="{@url}" method="xml">
        <xsl:copy-of select="$groups/group[$pos]/Node"/>
    </xsl:result-document>
</xsl:template>
```

to output the `Node` elements grouped earlier.